# how update the second row in oracle11g?

Tags: oracle11g

I tried this request:

```
UPDATE studentTble e SET e.oStudent.oPerson.oAddr.city='UK' WHERE rownum = 2
ID          NAME               STREET   CITY
100 --------Henrry.Student-----ST 17.---NY
101 --------Samm.Student-------ST 17D.--OR
102 --------Hanna.Student------ST 25D.--MX
```

Comment: And what is the problem? There is no question here. Upate the post to include a sentence ending with a question mark.

Comment: `WHERE rownum = 2` It is incorrect usage of rownum. IT is never incremented beyond 1 in this case, so there are no rows affected by it. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> WHERE rownum = 2

That is not how ROWNUM works. Rownum is not incremented to 2 unless Oracle assigns rownum to the first row. So, `WHERE ROWNUM = 2` would return **no rows**, since rownum is never incremented beyond 1 in this case.

> how update the second row in oracle11g?

There is nothing called a **Nth** row unless you have an ordered set of rows. In your case, if you have an explicit **ORDER BY** on **ID** column, by default in ascending order, then you could choose the second row from the **sub-query**.

```
UPDATE studenttble e 
SET    e.ostudent.operson.oaddr.city = 'UK' 
WHERE  id = (SELECT id 
             FROM   (SELECT id, 
                            ROWNUM rn 
                     FROM   (SELECT id, 
                                    ROWNUM rn 
                             FROM   studenttble 
                             ORDER  BY id)) 
             WHERE  rn = 2)
```

You could also use **ANALYTIC ROW_NUMBER()** to assign rank to each row ordered by ID column.